# add column to say which table a union result is from

Tags: mysql, union

How can I select which table each result is from, when I use a `UNION` command to search multiple tables?

For example, if there are results from both tables, how can I add a column that will say (or differentiate between) whether it is from tableA or tableB.

Comment: The accepted answer below will work, but is there another way that doesn't involve many nested selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one, simply add a *virtual column* for the name of the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 'tableA' as tableName FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'tableB' as tableName FROM tableB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'tableC' as tableName FROM tableC
) s
WHERE   colName = 'hello'
```