# Check if record is from table_b

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables(table_a and table_b) combined with a UNION.

How can I check if record ist table_a.

I tried this, but not working:

```
$res=mysql_query("(SELECT id, added FROM table_a WHERE user_id = '".$uid."') 
UNION 
(SELECT id as comments, added FROM table_b WHERE user_id = '".$uid."') ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 50");

if(!empty($rows["comments"])) // not working
```

Comment: I had the same question...I think...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598450/add-column-to-say-which-table-a-union-result-is-from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you forgot to read the result-set:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
// here you read $rows["comments"] etc
...

}
```

**Important:**
Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. 
Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

**Update:**
If you want to know from which table the result "came" you can change your query to:

```
(SELECT id, added, 'A' as came_from FROM table_a WHERE user_id = '".$uid."') 
UNION 
(SELECT id as comments, added, 'B' as came_from FROM table_b WHERE user_id = '".$uid."') ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 50
```

Then check the value of: `$rows["came_from "]`

Comment: Its written in my script...I just want to know how to check if row is from table_b